# One peer object handle multiple clients

Tags: python, tcp, client-server, twisted

**I have a server-client code using TCP and Twisted.** I want the first peer object that is created (*by order of the first connected client*) to serve (*send messages*) future upcoming clients as well. So I save the first peer (global list) and I use it for all upcoming connections but it only serves the first client (*that it's connected to*) while ignoring the others.

**How can I make the peer to serve all connected clients simultaneously?** (*I'll test it for no more than 3 clients*).

```
def connectionMade(self):
            global connectedList
    if self.pt == 'client':
        self.connected = True
    else:                 
        print "Connected from", self.transport.client
        try:
            self.transport.write('<connection up>')
        except Exception, e:
            print e.args[0]
        self.ts = time.time()
        reactor.callLater(5, self.sendUpdate)

    connectedList.append(self.transport) # add peer object




def sendUpdate(self):
            global updateCounter, connectedList
    print "Sending update"
    try:
                    updateCounter += 1
                    print(connectedList[0])
                    # Send updates through first connected peer
                    connectedList[0].write('<update ' + str(updateCounter) + '>')
    except Exception, ex1:
        print "Exception trying to send: ", ex1.args[0]
    if self.connected == True:
        reactor.callLater(5, self.sendUpdate)
```

Comment: Plz, give your code??

Comment: @sanduniYW code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to serve (send messages) future upcoming clients as well

This sentence is difficult to understand.  My interpretation is that you want `sendUpdate` to send messages to all of the clients except the first (ordered by when they connected).

> but it only serves the first client

This is similarly difficult.  My interpretation is that you observe a behavior in which only the first client (ordered by when they connected) receives any messages from the server.

Here is your code for sending messages to clients:

```
connectedList[0].write('<update ' + str(updateCounter) + '>')
```

Notice that this code always sends a message to `connectedList[0]`.  That is, it only sends a message to *one* client - regardless of how many there are - and it always selects the *first* client in `connectedList` (which corresponds to the first client to connect to the server).

You may want something more like this:

```
for c in connectedList[1:]:
    c.write('<update ' + str(updateCounter) + '>')
```

Notice how this sends a message to more than one client.

Also, unrelated to your question, you should eliminate your use of globals and you should avoid using a bare `ITransport` as your protocol interface.

Comment: Yes thank you that worked fine and it was really easy to understand after all.